Microsoft Graph Dedupe and Add Columns
I have the below PowerShell script where I want to make the following changes:

Dedupe the list of users as some users might have more than one license SKU. My current method adds a user more than once if they have more than one license SKU assigned. Each user should only be included in my list once.
Add a column for each license SKU to indicate true/false on whether the user has that specific license SKU. i.e. There should be a true/false column for each SKU (and the number of SKUs could change over time).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All","Group.ReadWrite.All" -NoWelcome
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$uri = [System.UriBuilder] 'https://graph.microsoft.com'

function Get-GroupMembersId {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string] $uri)

    do {
        $response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET $uri -Headers @{ ConsistencyLevel = 'eventual' }
        $uri = $response.'@odata.nextLink'
        if ($null -ne $response.value) {
            $response.value.Id
        }
    }
    while ($uri)
}

$tmSku = Get-MgSubscribedSku -All | Where SkuPartNumber -in ('SKU1', 'SKU2', 'SKU3', 'SKU4', 'SKU5')

foreach ($sku in $tmSku)
{

    $getMgUserSplat = @{
        Filter           = "assignedLicenses/any(x: x/skuId eq $($sku.SkuId))"
        Select           = 'DisplayName', 'Id', 'Mail', 'UserPrincipalName', 'JobTitle'
        All              = $true
    }

    $users += Get-MgUser @getMgUserSplat
    $userCount = $users | Measure-Object

}

$result = foreach ($user in $users) {
    $outObject = [ordered]@{
        Id                = $user.Id
        DisplayName       = $user.DisplayName
        UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
        Mail              = $user.Mail
        JobTitle          = $user.JobTitle
    }

    [pscustomobject] $outObject
}

Write-Host "Found " $userCount.Count  " licensed users."
$result 


Create 2 hashtables:

one for mapping user IDs to user objects

ensures we only store each user object once


one for maping SKUs to user IDs

needed to create and populate the SKU "columns" later



$tmSku = Get-MgSubscribedSku -All | Where SkuPartNumber -in ('SKU1', 'SKU2', 'SKU3', 'SKU4', 'SKU5')

# create a hashtable to keep track of users and their license assignments
$users = @{}
$assignedSKUs = @{}

foreach ($sku in $tmSku) {

    $getMgUserSplat = @{
        Filter           = "assignedLicenses/any(x: x/skuId eq $($sku.SkuId))"
        Select           = 'DisplayName', 'Id', 'Mail', 'UserPrincipalName', 'JobTitle'
        All              = $true
    }

    Get-MgUser @getMgUserSplat |ForEach-Object {
      # populate user table
      if (-not $users.Contains($_.Id)) {
        $users[$_.Id] = $_
      }

      # populate SKU table
      if (-not $assignedSKUs.Contains($sku.SkuId)) {
        # use a hashset to store the user IDs associated with a given SKU
        $assignedSKUs[$sku.SkuId] = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      }
      [void]$assignedSKUs[$sku.SkuId].Add($_.Id)
    }
}

Now that we've gathered the relevant information, iterate over the entries in the $users table to create each output record, with properties dynamically added based on the contents of the $assignedSKUs table:
$result = @(
  foreach ($userID in $users.psbase.Keys) {
    $user = $users[$userID]

    # create object template with ordered dictionary just like before
    $outObject = [ordered]@{
      Id                = $user.Id
      DisplayName       = $user.DisplayName
      UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
      Mail              = $user.Mail
      JobTitle          = $user.JobTitle
    }

    # ... but then we also attach and populate all SKU columns to it
    foreach ($sku in $tmSku) {
      $outObject[$sku.SkuId] = $assignedSKUs[$sku.SkuId].Contains($user.Id)
    }

    # ... and finally create the output object just like before
    [pscustomobject]$outObject
  }
)

Write-Host "Found $($result.Count) licensed users."

# turn the properties into "columns" in a CSV file
$result |Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path path\to\user_licenses.csv


This makes a lot of sense. I put it together, and replaced ForEach-Objects with ForEach-Object, but am getting a null-valued expression exception, even though my call to Get-MgUser is returning results.
ForEach-Object : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

@Mayhem My bad, the if condition expression -not $assignedSKUs.Contains($_.Id) should have been -not $assignedSKUs.Contains($sku.SkuId) (since we're testing whether a hashset has already been created for the given SKU, not the user), and a few other typos - should be fixed now :)

That did the trick. Thank you so much for this solution. This is really great and seems to work as expected. Really appreciate your efforts!

@Mayhem That's great to hear, you're most welcome! Consider marking my answer accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of it :)
